# Assign List value to Json list class

Tags: c#, json, list

I have a List class `List<Data> dataValue = new List<Data>` where Data contains List of destination's(multiple) and List of source's(multiple) details. I want to loop through and assign each of the destination and source to the List below. I am finally converting all the data to a JSON file.

```
foreach (var data in dataValue)
{
    var value = new RuleJsonclassTemplate
    {
        type = data.type,

        mapping = new List<Mapping>() { new Mapping() { value = data.destination, key = data.source } },

        description = data.description,
        title = data.title
    }
}

string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
string path = outputdir + Outputfilename;

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(JSONresult.ToString());
    writer.Close();
}

class Mapping
{
    public string destination { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON output should look like below,

```
{
    "type": "Type1",
    "mapping": [
        {
            "value": "destination1",
            "key": "source1"
        },
        {
            "value": "destination2",
            "key": "source1"
        },
        {
            "value": "destination3",
            "key": "source3"
        }
    ],
    "description": "Test description",
    "title": "Test title"
}
```

Can you please suggest on how can I achieve this? For reference my sample code at https://dotnetfiddle.net/W49buW

Comment: @SirRufo: Sorry, updated the desired JSON output. The code was also updated.

Comment: @SirRufo: Here is a suitable example I have added at https://dotnetfiddle.net/W49buW.

Answer (score 0):

It would be :

```
public string ConvertToJSON(List<string>SourceStr,List<string>DestinationStr)
{
    string json = "{" + Environment.NewLine + "mapping : [" + Environment.NewLine;
    for (int i = 0; i < SourceStr.Count; i++)
     {
       json = json + "{" + Environment.NewLine + "value : " + SourceStr[i].ToString() + ","+ Environment.NewLine
                + "key : " + DestinationStr[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "}," + Environment.NewLine;
     }
    json = json.Substring(0, json.LastIndexOf(','));
    json = json + "]" + Environment.NewLine + "}";
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Never, ever build JSON or XML or any structured data "by hand" - you should always use a **well tested** library

Comment: @SirRufo: Please check this sample dotnetfiddle.net/W49buW.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by adding another method which add's the data 1 by 1 to the list. Updated my sample code at https://dotnetfiddle.net/W49buW. Hope this helps for folks looking for the solution.